# Ubuntu Server: After Trying to Set Email Server Using Postfix, Ping 8.8.8.8 Only Gives Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hostname, netplan

This morning the connection and all the things were working fine, until I following some online tutorial, installed **Postfix** and changed **/etc/hostname** and **/etc/hosts**. Now ping to the local router: 198.168.3.1 is working fine, but not when I try to reach anywhere out of the firewall:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.3.46 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

ping 192.168.3.1
PING 192.168.3.1 (192.168.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.3.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=8.62 ms
```

I uninstalled **Postfix**, changed **/etc/hostname** and **/etc/hosts**, but the problem remains. 
I will use example.com to cover the real domain. Here's my *ifconfig* for the instance:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.46  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::bacb:29ff:fea3:a598  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:cb:29:a3:a5:98  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4377  bytes 708162 (708.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 28  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 875  bytes 62510 (62.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17
```

Here's my **/etc/netplan**:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [192.168.3.46/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.3.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8]
```

Here's the **/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.1.1 www.example.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here's the **/etc/hostname**:

```
example.com
```

The server still takes request, but cannot send anything past the LAN:

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8 traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
1  example.com (192.168.3.46)  2325.811 ms  2325.800 ms   2325.793 ms
```

I reset the Firewalls and did everything I can, someone please help...

Comment: Is your gateway supposed to be 192.168.3.254 or 192.168.3.1? Your netplan says the first but your question implies the second.

Comment: @icarus Thanks for replying, IP to the router is 192.168.3.1, and gateway4 is 192.168.3.254 (when i change it to anything else, it gives me error)

Comment: Can you edit the output of `ip route` into the question? Can you ping 192.168.3.254 from the machine? Are you sure that changing gateway4 to 192.168.3.1 gives you an error? If you can't fix your netplan, can you change the ip address of the router to 192.168.3.254?

Comment: @icarus man you the lifesaver, I was going to re-install the system... never thought could be caused by this. Found out 254 was pointing to another router, and now I just figure out what does gateway really means. Thank you for the help, have a great day :D

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All thanks to @icarus, just realize that the gateway and router should share the same address which handles all incoming and outgoing traffic. There were 2 routers working for a different purpose earlier, that's why the problem only occurred today because the other router's rule was changed.